# how to center and align texts by merging two images using PHP GD

Tags: php, gd

How do I centralize and align text above my main image?

The result of this code is this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cshtG.jpg

I wish it would look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Onp.jpg

but I do not understand much of moving the images and texts.

```html
<?php
$fontname = 'verdana.ttf';
$i = 30;
$quality = 85;
function create_image($user){
    global $fontname;
    global $quality;
    $file = md5($user[1]['text'].rand(30454, 343434)).".jpg";

    //if (!file_exists($file)) {
        $im   = imagecreatefromjpeg("fundo.jpg");
        $logo = imagecreatefromjpeg("img.jpeg"); 
        $color['grey']  = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $y = imagesy($im) - $height - 365;
        $font_size = 25;
        $logo_x = imagesx($logo); 
        $logo_y = imagesy($logo); 
        
        foreach ($user as $value){
            $x = center_text($value['text'], $font_size);
            imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, $x, $y+$i, $color["grey"], $fontname, $value['text']);
            $i = $i+32;

        }
        imagecopymerge($im, $logo, 37, 370, 0, 0, $logo_x, $logo_y, 100);
        imagejpeg($im, $file, $quality);
    //}
    return $file;
}

function center_text($string, $font_size) {
    global $fontname;
    $image_width = 720;
    $dimensions = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $fontname, $string);
    return ceil(($image_width - $dimensions[4]) / 2);
}

$user = array(
    array('text'=> 'Our adge lacks gravitas. That’s whyaadasdasdasdasdsadasdasdasdas')
);
$filename = create_image($user);
?>
<img src="<?=$filename;?>" /><br/><br/>
```

Comment: Is your problem finding the right x and y coordinates of the text before adding it to the image, or is it finding a way to calculate text height (and wrapping on multiple lines)?

Answer (score 0):

Aligning text in an image using PHP's image functions is always a bit of a puzzle.

First, you need to know the x and y coordinates of the point at the bottom center of where the text should go (anchor point). This is probably half the width of the outer image for the x and the y value of the top of the smaller image in the center (minus a margin value) for the y.

After this, you have to calculate where your text has to be put (x and y) so that it will align above the smaller image in the center (centered above the anchor point).

For this you use `imagettfbbox` to calculate what the bounding box's coordinates will be if the text is put at x=0 y=0. Then you use these values to calculate the coordinates of the bottom center of this bounding box.

```
$bounding_box = imagettfbbox(......);

/* lower right x - lower left x, divided by 2 */
$relative_x = ( $bounding_box[2] - $bounding_box[0] ) / 2;
/* lower left y */
$relative_y = $bounding_box[1];
```

Subtracting these relative values from our first calculated anchor point, gives you the coordinates to put the text using `imagettftext`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php for which array value is which coordinate value.